# Append row in Sql without replacing previous row java

Tags: java, sql, sql-insert

So i have database with value like this...[image]

i'm trying to append the value by using insert into without replacing it,the data from this txt file...
[image]

but when i reload/refresh the database there is no new data being appended into the database...,
here is my code....

```
public static void importDatabase(String fileData){
    try{
        File database = new File(fileData);
        FileReader fileInput = new FileReader(database);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileInput);
        String line = in.readLine();
        line = in.readLine();
        String[] data;
        while (line != null){
        data = line.split(",");
        int ID = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        String Nama = data[1];
        int Gaji = Integer.parseInt(data[2]);
        int Absensi = Integer.parseInt(data[3]);
        int cuti = Integer.parseInt(data[4]);
        String Status = data[5];

        String query = "insert into list_karyawan values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = getConn().prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1,ID);
        ps.setString(2,Nama);
        ps.setInt(3,Gaji);
        ps.setInt(4,Absensi);
        ps.setInt(5,cuti);
        ps.setString(6,Status);
        line = in.readLine();
        }
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        con.close();
        System.out.println("Database Updated");
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

> When i run it, it shows no error but the data never get into database, where did i go wrong?.,...

Comment: Do you use a transaction? Maybe you are missing a commit.

Comment: only a simple java database application...

Comment: when i use commit it shows java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true

Comment: Then try to select the record that yo just add.
Also, don't you have to execute         ps.executeUpdate(); in every cycle instead of making it at the end?

Comment: i've insert the ps.excetue to the while loop, but it shows duplicate ID instead of append the value into new rows

Comment: And instead, if you try to select the value that you  just add it return something?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-commit mode is enabled by default.
The JDBC driver throws a SQLException when a commit or rollback operation is performed on a connection that has auto-commit set to true.
Symptoms of the problem can be unexpected application behavior
update the JVM configuration for the ActiveMatrix BPM node to use the following Oracle          connection property:

autoCommitSpecCompliant=false  Try once

Note:I am not able to put as comment so i posted as a answer